# How to fix? Tx nonce go out of sync when using multiple unit tests on the same contract under Ganache+Truffle

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, ganache, unittesting, ganache-cli

Here is my example contract (ignore the fact this could be pure, this is a simplified example and my real example is not a pure function, it changes state, but I can reproduce the bug with this simple example):

```
    pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
    contract Hello {
        function hello() external {
        }
    }
```

and unit test:

```js
    const Hello = artifacts.require("./Hello.sol");
    contract("Hello", accounts => {
        it("should hello", async () => {
            const hello = await Hello.deployed();
            await hello.hello({from : accounts[0]});
        });
    });
```

the above works fine on `truffle develop` or on `truffle migrate` + Ganache (GUI or CLI).

Now if I want to have two unit tests (for simplicity I've done the same one twice, in reality I would use different unit tests)

```js
    const Hello = artifacts.require("./Hello.sol");
    contract("Hello", accounts => {
        it("should hello", async () => {
            const hello = await Hello.deployed();
            await hello.hello({from : accounts[0]});
        });
        it("should hello", async () => {
            const hello = await Hello.deployed();
            await hello.hello({from : accounts[0]});
        });
    });
```

Again this works fine on `truffle develop` or on `truffle migrate` + Ganache (GUI or CLI).

Now if I want to reset the state of the contract between each unit test (imagine hello() changes the state and I want to revert back to the way it was for the next unit test), the way I've been doing it is like this

```js
    const Hello = artifacts.require("./Hello.sol");
    contract("Hello", accounts => {
        it("should hello", async () => {
            const hello = await Hello.deployed();
            await hello.hello({from : accounts[0]});
        });
    });
    contract("Hello", accounts => {
        it("should hello", async () => {
            const hello = await Hello.deployed();
            await hello.hello({from : accounts[0]});
        });
    });
```

this works fine if I just do this under `truffle develop`. But if I try to use `truffle migrate` + Ganache (GUI or CLI) I get an error like this:

```
Error: the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 162 tx has nonce of: 163
```

the numbers don't have to be exactly 162 and 163, I've just been running the example a lot, it could be 1 and 2. But they are always out of sync by one if I call `contract` twice in the unit test but not when I call `it` twice within one call to `contract`.

Comment: Use a single `contract` per unit-test (i.e., per JS file located under the `test` folder).

Comment: The reason I was using multiple `contract` is if you use one, the state persists from one unit test to the next and I need it to reset. How do I avoid state persisting between tests?

Comment: The state do not persist! You must be doing something wrong somewhere else. Try to "disable the activity" in your `1_initial_migration.js` file (something like, do it only `if (network !== "development")`).

Comment: what does "disable the activity" mean? Can you give an example of how `1_initial_migration.js` should look?

I just created a new fresh test project to make sure I haven't set anything up wrong. Having the state persist between tests seems to be the default behaviour for truffle test. Here's all the code in the new project: https://pastebin.com/ugBPLu86

Comment: Just get rid of your `1_deploy_contracts.js` file (btw, its name should start with `2` I believe), and change `Hello.deployed()` to `new Hello()` in all your tests.

Comment: If you want to keep `1_deploy_contracts.js` for your actual deployment, then add `if (network !== "development")` in it, to prevent it from doing anything when you execute `truffle test`.

Comment: it seems that `new Hello()` throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined`. I was following the Drizzle React Tutorial ( https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-drizzle-and-react ) when I started using unit tests with solidity. It indicates the way to do it is `const myStringStore = await MyStringStore.deployed();`

Comment: You've used `await new Hello()`, right?

Comment: I did `const hello = new Hello();` but just now I've tried changing it to `const hello = await new Hello();` and both cases throw the error. It still throws the error if I remove the lines afterwards (so that this is the only line in the unit test) suggesting the error is being thrown within the constructor (I think).

Comment: Do you run `truffle test` or what?

Comment: I'm in the `truffle develop` developer console. Inside there I ran `compile`, `migrate` and `test`. If I `.exit` out of the console and run `truffle test` I get the same error.

Comment: Oh okay I think I have it fixed now. I found in a different thread here it's actually `await Hello.new()` not `await new Hello()`